# Убрать вторичные вкладки

Tags: java, javafx, tab

Есть макет:
[image: макет]

в результате написания кода получаю

[image: результат]

**Вопрос:** как убрать верхнюю строчку с закрывающимися вкладками и оставить только как на макете?

структура проекта:
-[src]
.....|-[sample]
..............|- Main
..............|- sample.fxml
..............|- SampleController
..............|- Tab1.fxml
..............|- Tab1Controller
..............|- Tab2.fxml
..............|- Tab2Controller

**КОД**
класс **Main**

```
package sample;  
import javafx.application.Application;  
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;  
import javafx.scene.Scene;  
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;  
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;  
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;  
import javafx.stage.Stage;  
import java.io.IOException;  
public class Main extends Application {  

private Stage primary;
private BorderPane rootLayout;


@Override
public void start(Stage primary) throws Exception{
   this.primary = primary;

   initRootLayout();
   showTab();
}

private void initRootLayout() {
    try {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("sample.fxml"));

        rootLayout = loader.load();

        Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);

        primary.setScene(scene);
        primary.show();

    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();}

}


private void showTab() {
    try {

        FXMLLoader loaderTab1 = new FXMLLoader();
        loaderTab1.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("Tab1.fxml"));

        FXMLLoader loaderTab2 = new FXMLLoader();
        loaderTab2.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("Tab2.fxml"));

        TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();

        Tab tab1 = new Tab();
        Tab tab2 = new Tab();


        tab1.setContent(loaderTab1.load());
        tab2.setContent(loaderTab2.load());

        tabPane.getTabs().addAll(tab1,tab2);


        rootLayout.setCenter(tabPane);

    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

**sample.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>

<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.172-ea" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.SampleController">
   <top>
      <MenuBar BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <menus>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
        </menus>
      </MenuBar>
   </top>
</BorderPane>
```

**Tab1.fxml** = Tab2.fxml = ... = Tab{n}.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Tab?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TabPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>

<TabPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Tab1Controller">
  <tabs>
      <Tab text="Tab1">
         <content>
            <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.29797979797979796" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="200.0">
              <items>
                <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0">
                     <children>
                        <TableView fixedCellSize="1.0" layoutX="-12.0" layoutY="27.0" prefHeight="371.0" prefWidth="176.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                          <columns>
                            <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="C1" />
                            <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="C2" />
                          </columns>
                           <columnResizePolicy>
                              <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
                           </columnResizePolicy>
                        </TableView>
                     </children></AnchorPane>
                <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0">
                     <children>
                        <Label layoutY="14.0" text="Label" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="14.0" />
                        <GridPane layoutX="98.0" layoutY="125.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="35.0">
                          <columnConstraints>
                            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                          </columnConstraints>
                          <rowConstraints>
                            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                          </rowConstraints>
                           <children>
                              <Label text="Label" />
                              <Label text="Label" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                              <Label text="Label" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                              <Label text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
                              <Label text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                              <Label text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                           </children>
                        </GridPane>
                     </children></AnchorPane>
              </items>
            </SplitPane>
         </content></Tab>
  </tabs>
</TabPane>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос решен, всем спасибо!
Добавляемые вкладки - это не вкладки **TabPane** или **Tab**, а просто отображения! В моем случае - **SplitPane**

**исправления**
классе **Main**

```
private void showTab() {
    try {

        FXMLLoader loaderTab1 = new FXMLLoader();
        loaderTab1.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("Tab1.fxml"));

        FXMLLoader loaderTab2 = new FXMLLoader();
        loaderTab2.setLocation(Main.class.getResource("Tab2.fxml"));

        TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();

        Tab tab1 = new Tab();
        Tab tab2 = new Tab();

        tab1.setContent(loaderTab1.load());
        tab2.setContent(loaderTab2.load());

        tab1.closableProperty().set(false);
        tab1.setText("Tab 1");
        tab2.closableProperty().set(false);
        tab2.setText("Tab 2");

        tabPane.getTabs().addAll(tab1,tab2);

        rootLayout.setCenter(tabPane);
        } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
                }
}
```

исправленный **Tab1.fxml**=Tab2.fxml=...=Tab{n}.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>


            <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.29797979797979796" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0"  xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Tab1Controller">
              <items>
                <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0">
                     <children>
                        <TableView fixedCellSize="1.0" layoutX="-12.0" layoutY="27.0" prefHeight="371.0" prefWidth="176.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                          <columns>
                            <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="C1" />
                            <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="C2" />
                          </columns>
                           <columnResizePolicy>
                              <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
                           </columnResizePolicy>
                        </TableView>
                     </children></AnchorPane>
                <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0">
                     <children>
                        <Label layoutY="14.0" text="Label" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="14.0" />
                        <GridPane layoutX="98.0" layoutY="125.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="5.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="35.0">
                          <columnConstraints>
                            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                          </columnConstraints>
                          <rowConstraints>
                            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                          </rowConstraints>
                           <children>
                              <Label text="Label" />
                              <Label text="Label" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                              <Label text="Label" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                              <Label text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
                              <Label text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                              <Label text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                           </children>
                        </GridPane>
                     </children></AnchorPane>
              </items>
            </SplitPane>
```

результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]